# Jpa. Как записать запрос в jparepository?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Есть список популярных запросов

```
@Entity
public class PopularSearch extends BaseEntity{
    private String searchStr;
    private Long count;
}
```

Нужно взять пять самых популярных. Делаю так

```
@Repository
public interface PopularSearchRepository extends BaseRepository<PopularSearch> {
    List<PopularSearch> findTop5OrderByCountDesc();
}
```

Выдают исключение `PopularSearchRepository.findTop5OrderByCountDesc()! No property desc found for type Long! Traversed path: PopularSearch.count`
Если записать `findTop5BySearchStrOrderByCountDesc(String s)` то все компилируется хорошо. Можно ли записать таким образом подобный запрос? Можно записать через jpql, конечно, но интересно возможно ли этим способом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация говорит, что `By` является разделителем, после которого начинается критерий, который включает в себя и сортировку:

> the first By acts as delimiter to indicate the start of the actual criteria

Вот примеры из [документации](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result), когда нет собственно фильтра:

```
User findFirstByOrderByLastnameAsc();

User findTopByOrderByAgeDesc();
```

Так что в вашем случае нужно использовать такое имя: `findTop5ByOrderByCountDesc`

Answer (score 1):

После Top5 нужен By даже если нет параметра для поиска.

```
findTop5ByOrderByCountDesc
```